# invalid date in NSDateFormatter

Tags: ios, objective-c, cocoa-touch, nsdate, nsdateformatter

```
self.dateFormatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
[self.dateFormatter setTimeZone:[NSTimeZone timeZoneWithName:@"UTC"]];
[self.dateFormatter setLocale:[[NSLocale alloc] initWithLocaleIdentifier:@"en_US_POSIX"]];
[self.dateFormatter setDateFormat:@"yyyyMMdd"];

NSDate *date = [NSDate date];
NSString *dateString = [self.dateFormatter stringFromDate:date];
```

this code sometimes returns for me incorrect date such as 201300090005. 
I don't understand why.

Comment: Are you *certain* that's the format string you are using?  It doesn't make alot of sense.

Comment: you can try this format [self.dateFormatter setDateFormat:@"yyyy-MM-dd"];

Comment: Since he wants the string of today's date, date format is irrelevant with the suggested problem. Code looks just fine, it seems rather impossible.

Comment: the format is incorrect. try '[self.dateFormatter setDateFormat:@"yyyy-MM-dd"];'

Comment: His format is perfectly legitimate.  Either there's a bug in NSDateFormatter (which I doubt) or there's something else going on in code outside what's quoted above (which is much more likely).

Comment: You should show the NSLog output of the raw `date` together with `dateString` for a failing case.

Comment: @MartinR - And also the NSLog of the resulting string, taken immediately after the formatting operation.

Comment: This code is working fine.

Comment: @Hot Licks is right. There is something wrong out side the code

Answer (score 0):

I tried the something like this, but it always works fine for me:-

```
NSDateFormatter *dateFormatter = [[[NSDateFormatter alloc] init]autorelease];
[dateFormatter setTimeZone:[NSTimeZone timeZoneWithName:@"UTC"]];
[dateFormatter setLocale:[[NSLocale alloc] initWithLocaleIdentifier:@"en_US_POSIX"]];
[dateFormatter setDateFormat:@"yyyyMMdd"];

NSDate *date = [NSDate date];
NSString *dateString = [dateFormatter stringFromDate:date];
NSLog(@"yourDateString=%@",dateString);
```